# Issue after upgrade flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I have this issue after upgrade flutter ...

```
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
```

I havn't this issue before.
Any idea ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone: [issue #34915](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34915)

As MisterJimson commented:

> this seemed to be related to duplicate keys in a list. Removing the
>   dupes fixed the issue.